# Gradle Java plugin and Multi-Projects: Why does jar task doesn't depend on check?

Tags: gradle

According to http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html and Figure 23.1, the jar task depends on the classes task.

In my scenario I have a multi project containing three projects - ProjectCommon, ProjectApp1 and ProjectApp2. ProjectApp1 depends on ProjectCommon, ProjectApp2 depends on ProjectCommon.

Here's the build.gradle of ProjectApp1 and ProjectApp2:

```
dependencies {
    compile         project(':ProjectCommon')    
}
```

I wan't to build now only ProjectApp1, using

```
$ gradle :ProjectApp1:build
```

The output shows, that e.g. test and check of ProjectCommon is not executed:

```
:ProjectCommon:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectCommon:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectCommon:classes UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectCommon:jar
:ProjectApp1:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectApp1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectApp1:classes UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectApp1:jar
:ProjectApp1:assemble
:ProjectApp1:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectApp1:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectApp1:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:ProjectApp1:test
:ProjectApp1:check
:ProjectApp1:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.633 secs
```

ProjectApp1 is now built without knowing if ProjectCommon is really fine...

(of course I could do gradle :ProjectCommon:build :ProjectApp1:build instead to avoid this).

**Wouldn't it be "safer", if jar would generally depend on check?**

Or am I doing something wrong with the dependencies and I better should use in build.gradle of ProjectApp1 and ProjectApp2:

```
dependsOn(':ProjectCommon')
```

(which gives a deprecation warning)

Answer (score 2):

The Gradle Java plugin uses project compile dependencies only for certain tasks, the check task is not one of them.

In ProjectApp1, add

```
check {
    dependsOn ':ProjectCommon:check'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ingo Kegel! What do you think about instead adding subprojects { jar.dependsOn('check') } only to the build.gradle in root?

Comment: Not sure I understand this. But you could enumerate all subprojects in your root project with `subprojects {}` and add dependencies as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `jar` task doesn't depend on the `check` task because they have no *semantic* dependency - the latter doesn't produce anything that the former consumes.

> Wouldn't it be "safer", if jar would generally depend on check?

It would cost time without being any safer in some cases (e.g. Java compilation), and would not be safe enough in other cases (e.g. when publishing related projects, where you want *all* projects to be tested before publishing *any* of them). With Gradle, you can tailor the behavior to the particular needs.

The Java plugin provides a `buildNeeded` task, which fully builds upstream projects before building downstream projects. In a similar fashion, it would be possible to make Gradle test upstream projects before using their outputs in downstream projects. The question is how useful this would be.

Comment: Thanks +Peter Niederwieser for your explanations. Before I used gradle, I was used to "jar" my stuff at the end, after all tests/checks were "green". With gradle "jar" depends directly on "classes", which is nicely documented in Figure 23.1 of the Java plugin documentation. I just have to change some old habits and my thinking... ;-)